# how to upload image from application using php mysql Xcode and save as filesystem as well as database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, iphone, xcode

i am trying to upload image in database as well as in server some folder how ever in folder i am getting image but always only one when i upload it replace existing what i upload before and not even saving in my data base is empthy i want to save image in database as well as in filesystem for my further web use. i know i either i am missing something but i don`t know what i am kinda new please help my code is

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageview.image,90);
                NSString *urlString = @"http://befirstwin.com/upload.php";
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
                [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

                NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
                NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
                [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                // file
                NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                //[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", uname]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
                [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                // close form
                [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                // set request body
                [request setHTTPBody:body];
                //return and test
                NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
                NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:returnString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
```

for php

```
<?php

//my connection


$abdb = $_FILES['userfile']; //getting image Here //getting textLabe Here 
    $target_path = "abdbphoto/";
     if(move_uploaded_file($abdb['tmp_name'], $target_path . basename( $abdb['name'])))

    { echo "The file ". basename( $abdb['name']). " has been uploaded"; } 

    else 

    {
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
     } 
   if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) { 

      // Temporary file name stored on the server
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];  
      $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);



if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

      // Create the query and insert
      // into our database.
     $query = "INSERT INTO pictures (image ) ".
"VALUES ('$content')";
      $result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result)
{
die("we have problem");
}
else
{
      // Print results
      print "Thank you, your file has been uploaded.";
}
}
else {
   print "No image selected/uploaded";
}   
mysql_close();
?>
```

please check it out and please suggest what i am missing and with image database file i have my email id to i don`t know how to send it at same time .. thanks in advance

Comment: any one will get that what i am doing wrong if yes please suggest !! i am stuck out .. @ashish kakkad